# A question about protected extra-low voltage system

Tags: power-supply, extra-low-voltage

I don't understand what is meant by the following about PELV:

On wiki it says the AC RMS range must be smaller than 50V and DC must be smaller than 120V. Is AC limit here for the output of the power supply?

It also mentions:

> IEC 61140 defines a PELV system as "an electrical system in which the
>   voltage cannot exceed ELV under normal conditions, and under
>   single-fault conditions, except earth faults in other circuits".
>
> A PELV circuit only requires protective-separation from all circuits
>   other than SELV and PELV (i.e., all circuits that might carry higher
>   voltages), but it may have connections to other PELV systems and earth
>   (ground).
>
> In contrast to a SELV circuit, a PELV circuit can have a protective
>   earth (ground) connection. A PELV circuit, just as with SELV, requires
>   a design that guarantees a low risk of accidental contact with a
>   higher voltage. For a transformer, this can mean that the primary and
>   secondary windings must be separated by an extra insulation barrier,
>   or by a conductive shield with a protective earth connection

Since these are confusing to me I wanted to ask this on a practical example.

My question is:

Is [this SMPS](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/1621/0900766b81621f31.pdf) PELV? And how can I understand whether it is or not? And in what circumstance PELV would be safe?

Comment: What power supply do you refer to? Where's the wiki link?

Comment: This one https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/1621/0900766b81621f31.pdf I updated the pdf in question  as well. What makes PELV different than this? Im trying to understand what PELV is about by examples.

Comment: The term PELV applies to the entire circuit or system, not just to one element of it such as a power supply.

Comment: @Finbarr Are you sure? I saw power supply safety standard categories and one of them is PELV another one for example is SELV.  See this PSU for example: https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/1546/0900766b81546302.pdf At page 3, at "Standards" it says PELV (EN/IEC 60204-1). So they are selling a power supply which conforms this standard. What does it mean PELV in this context?

Comment: It means that it satisfies the requirements for use in a PELV circuit. But so must every other part of that circuit in order to make the whole circuit PELV. Remember, a chain is only as strong as its weakest link...

Comment: Your component links to RS are all broken.